# Cannot copy directory in MacOS with terminal

Tags: terminal

Input

```
$ pwd /Users/kylefoley/library/containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/data/library/Autosave Information

$cp /Users/kylefoley/library/containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/data/library/Autosave\ Information /Volumes/old/QT_screen_recs
```

Output

```
/Users/kylefoley/library/containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/data/library/Autosave Information is a directory (not copied).
```

I don't understand why this is not working.  I've also tried:

```
$cp /Users/kylefoley/library/containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/data/library/Autosave\ Information/* /Volumes/old/QT_screen_recs
```

Which yields:

```
/Users/kylefoley/library/containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/data/library/Autosave Information/*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I would try putting " around the file glob (the path ending in *) rather than the escape of the space

Comment: I had the best experiences with `cp -rf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want copy a directory with command cp you need add option -r or -a.
-a is best because it preserves the structure and attributes of files as indicated in the man command :

```
man cp
```

In your case if *QT_screen_recs* is a directory the corrects commands are :

```
cp -r /Users/kylefoley/library/containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/data/library/Autosave\ Information /Volumes/old/QT_screen_recs
```

or

```
cp -a /Users/kylefoley/library/containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/data/library/Autosave\ Information /Volumes/old/QT_screen_recs
```